# Google colab TPU bugged or I do something wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

Trying to port my dcgan to tpu.
But this error:

```
Error recorded from training_loop: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented
```

Here is notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/101FjBAIMVuXyNyeUvq_Vfx-Z6CR3g4df

Answer (score 1):

The local filesystem is not [available](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#cannot_use_local_filesystem) on Cloud TPU's. You can use Google Cloud Storage (GCS), like in this [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shakespeare_with_tpuestimator.ipynb). GCS is [free](https://cloud.google.com/free/) up to 5GB a month.

Alternatively Keras models running on TPU's copy variables back to the CPU so they can be used without GCS for the model directory.

Comment: Heh, it weird a bit since tpu estimator works ok from keras model like here.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uiCc3stWWeG1WZLO8xIIQkvKFeZ8Nwht?authuser=1#scrollTo=59Ku04UErf8k

So, maybe I just should turn off autosave? But I don't see where I can do it.

Comment: Keras works in a slightly different way, which lets you avoid GCS dependancy. So that is another option. Updated the answer

Comment: So, no way to turn off auto saving? It would be a simpler solution.